# Does not succeed verifying my website for SSL

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to set SSL certification through Microsoft Azure.
I purchased SSL certification and basically followed the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site

However, I'm stuck in the Verify stage for quite a few hours.
I'm trying to verify using my DNS zone file. According to the instructions I get in Azure's wizard:
[image]

I added the following Zone record.
[image]

But when I hit 'refresh' my website does not verify. Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [atilce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site#advanced), you will find you should add txt record as below:
DNS TXT Record Verification:

Using your DNS manager, Create a TXT record on the @ subdomain with value equal to the Domain Verification Token.

Click “Refresh” to update the Certificate status after verification is completed.

So I suggest you could add record as below:

GoDaddy manage DNS as below:
[image]

Or you could add txt record as below:

```
@.<domain> with value <verification-token>
```

After 5-10 minutes, you could refresh the domain verification, it will work well.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know how did you manage to verify. I put all three options: "@.mydomain.co.il TXT <mytoken>", "@ TXT <mytoken>", and "dzc.mydomain.co.il TXT <mytoken>". Nothing seems to work, it is still does not verify. It's been two days already, frustrating!

Comment: I suggest you could check the certificate service's distinguished name again, make sure the name is as same as your custom domain. For example, the domain is azureclubs.com, then the certificate service's distinguished name is azureclubs.com. Besides, you could try Mail Verification and HTML Verification in this article:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site#advanced.